# Get remote path of current location

Tags: php, directadmin

I am making a reseller hosting, for my own clients, but now I want to store my user-backups on a different host. So use a cronjob to do this.

But now my cronjob asks me for a Remote path to store the backups on.

I just want them in the /backups folder, but I guess I can't just fill in /backups in the remote path?

So how can I see what the full pathname is?

My idea was to create a .php file, and echo the remote path with some code.

I can't find the code on the internet so I asked it here.

Comment: It might help to see the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a path of a other machine with PHP, then thats do the trick:

```
echo __FILE__; // Full Filename
// OR
echo basedir( __FILE__ ); // Only the Path
```